# Slicing a Sphere

Tags: modeling, animation

I am a newbie to Blender, and would like to:

1. Create a hollowed sphere with a thickness.
2. Be able to slice it horizontally and vertically
3. Be able to select each piece, modify it and animate it

In short, I'd like to compose/decompose a sphere using Blender editors, animate the slices to do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>M</kbd>, <kbd>U</kbd> Add *UV Sphere*.
2. <kbd>F9</kbd> Set resolution for slicing.
3. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd>, <kbd>F3</kbd> `Edge Split`, <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd>.
4. [image] Add a new vertex group `SHELL`.

[image]

5. Add *Solidify Modifier*, set **Thickness to 0**, Output Vertex Groups → **Shell** to `SHELL`; <kbd>✲ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> Apply the modifier.
6. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd>, <kbd>⎇ Alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> deselect.
7. [image] Select vertices from `SHELL`, then <kbd>S</kbd> scale them up or down a bit (depending on how much thickness you want to have).

[image]

8. <kbd>A</kbd> select all [I moved the sphere to confirm/show all vertices are selected], <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>N</kbd> Recalculate normals.
9. <kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd> Separate by Loose Parts. <kbd>⭾ Tab</kbd>.

[image]

You now have a sliced sphere. The slices can be animated independently using the <kbd>`I`</kbd> key:

[image]

Consider selecting all pieces and then <kbd>F3</kbd> and search for "set origin…".

Comment: Thank you. It looks likes a very elaborated solution. I am on a MacBook Air without a mouse so I am kinda stuck with step 2, where you brought up the property list to change the segments and rings.

Comment: The playback goes a bit fast. If there is a convenient way to slow it down, I'd appreciate it very much. I had wanted to get a complete horizontal and vertical slices, which would divide a sphere into a set of rings. Your solution seems to offer a finer granularity, which is very good too, as it will give me more flexibility down the line. As I work through your solution, I should be able to reconstruct the pieces you generated into a ring. At any rate, if you have a quick offhand solution to do so, I'd appreciate it very much too. Thanks for the time and helps.

Comment: @AnhNguyen I don't use Apple products unfortunately, If you can't open the last operator settings with F9, you can look for a collapsed windows in the bottom-left corner and click it: https://i.imgur.com/nCtjWaA.png

Comment: @MarkusBroady I noticed that you don't use Apple. After playing around for awhile I was able to go pass step 1,2, &3. I am stuck at 4 as the new vertex group item field is not editable for me to enter the name. I did the followings to create the new vertex group <object data properties> <+>. Any clues?

Comment: @AnhNguyen double-click the name to edit it. At least on Windows.

Comment: @MarkusBroady as it turned out I needed to double click on the empty vertex group name per this instruction  https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/properties/vertex_groups/assigning_vertex_group.html to make the field editable

Comment: @MarkusBroady After step 9, I don't seem to be able to separate the loose parts as intended. Clicking on the sphere no matter where after step 9, the entire sphere object is selected. Please help explain what I am missing. BTW, how do you insert the screen capture in stackexchange?

Comment: @AnhNguyen I don't know a program for Mac to do that. You probably missed step 3 or 8.

Comment: @MarkBroady I solved this problem. It was due to the improper creation of Edge Split. To solve the problem I chose split by faces by edges by vertexes.

Comment: @MarkusBroady Thanks again.